# "Wind up with a toddler" meaning

Tags: meaning

In the big bang theory, season 1 episode 1, Sheldon said "What if she winds up with a toddler who doesn't know if he should use an integral or a differential to solve the area under a curve", how to understand the "winds up with a toddler"? I think it's equal to "raise a baby". Is this phrase very popular in the US?

Comment: Remember, if you are watching a comedy, that *everything* is under the "rule of funny".  Normal people don't talk like Sheldon, because normal people aren't characters in a comedy. You would never normally talk about "winding up with a toddler who ..."  It is an intrinsically funny thing to say.

Comment: But https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/wind-up  "be somewhere, or do something, without having planned it"

Comment: As an idiomatic usage, I think [***to wind up with](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will+wind+up+with%2Cwill+end+up+with&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) [some inferior result]*** is getting a bit past its sell-by date. Better to stick with ***end up with***, which never really went out of style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Wind up with” (something) generally means that (something) is the result or consequence of whatever you are talking about.

Sheldon is talking about donating sperm. He is worried that this will result in someone having a toddler that is bad at math.

It is humorous, in part, because most toddlers haven’t even started to learn math (especially calculus), which essentially means that Sheldon’s standard of intelligence is extremely high.